# permisioning for jmxremote.password file

Tags: java, jmx

I want to enable jmx on a java process to connect it with Visual VM.
I have placed following jvm parameters at startup:

```
    # JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
    # JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
    # JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$JMXREMORT_PASSWORD"
    # JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

I have been told that `jmxremote.password` file should have 600 as file permission set to it. But the issue is that deployment is done via admin user and run user is part of same group as admin. So giving 600 implies that run user is not able to access the file.
I tried changing permission to 660 but it didn't help and i got this error:
"Error: Password file read access must be restricted"

Any suggestion?

Comment: chown the file to the run user

Answer (score 0):

The `jmxremote.password` has to have owner set to the same as the user/service which started the java runtime (it can be checked in the services under "Log On As"). So make sure you set the access and the password's before you change the permissions.

Note: The access and password file should not have permissions given to any other user/service. It should only contain the owner. Otherwise you will get an error saying `Read access must be restricted`